# What is the most efficient way to use onChange event and useState on Text Field Element

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Code example;

```
<TextField id="name" onChange={(e: any) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name}> </TextField>
```

In this case; Is TextField rerendering when I press any character? Or Just value is changing?

If Element itself will be re-render, Is it the best way to do this?

Note: I set name to value because I have a form and if I come back to the screen I want to set state value to the TextField value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [avoid constant re-render from "input" or "textarea" in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942476/avoid-constant-re-render-from-input-or-textarea-in-react-js)

Comment: From which library the TextField is coming from ?

Comment: I looked the solution which you send, but my element is controlled element I think, it is Material-UI element. Should I create a new component for TextField and then should I use this statefull component? @JonnelVeXuZDorotan

Comment: Material-UI @tsamaya

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to separate stateful components into smaller components to avoid re-rendering if the props for that component haven't changed.

If all the individual `<TextField>` elements are in one large parent component, React will need to compare the requested UI structure of the entire form every time.

Also, use the [React DevTools -> Profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html) to see what parts are slow.

And, [React DevTools -> Components -> Settings -> *Highlight updates when components render*](https://blog.logrocket.com/make-react-fast-again-part-3-highlighting-component-updates-6119e45e6833/).

Comment: I will try to create a statefull component for this TextField then I will see what is happening. Thanks